# Azure Web App + Active Directory with domain mapping issue

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, multiple-domains

I have published an application as an Azure WebApp which uses Azure ActiveDirectory for my authentication.

This requires a redirect to AD and re routes back to my web app after authenticated.

This works flawlessly using the xxxx.azurewebsites.net uri, but is not working properly with domain masking.

How can I use my custom domain with ActiveDir auth?

The masking works without the azure auth, but the reply URL throws an error (which I will post soon).

Comment: Have you added the custom domain as a reply URL to the app in AAD?

Comment: @juunas yes I have

Comment: @TomCrosman Have you secured your custom domain with ssl binding? The reply url configured in azure ad must start with `https`. So your custom domain url must be totally the same as the reply url.

Comment: Yes, I paid for and implemented SSL.  Thank you for the guess though.

Comment: @TomCrosman The issue still exists even if you used https?

Comment: @Caiui Ju yes, even when Https

Comment: @TomCrosman This does't make sense.  What is the error message?

Comment: The error says the reply URLs don’t match.  But I configured them correctly...

Comment: @TomCrosman You can catch the redirect_uri in the browser.

Comment: @TomCrosman The reply url should be something like `https://xxx.xxx.com/.auth/login/aad/callback`

Comment: @TomCrosman https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJjUZ.jpg Check it with the reply url you configured on Azure portal.

Comment: Yeah my redirect shows as expected in the url

Comment: @TomCrosman Can you provide the reply url configured on Azure portal?